# how to install git without sudo on linux server

Tags: linux, git, installation, sudo

I tried the following to install git without sudo permissions

```
wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.1.2.tar.gz -O git.tar.gz
tar -zxf git.tar.gz

cd git-2.1.2/

make configure
./configure --prefix=/usr/local

make install
```

Can anyone help me how to install git with out sudo?

Comment: No need to put an image in  the question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)-ed software, you could decide to `configure` it with `--prefix=$HOME/soft/` (or some other prefix belonging to you)

Then, since `$HOME/soft/` is a directory belonging to you, you won't need any `sudo` for installation

Of course you'll want to add `$HOME/soft/bin/` to your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

You may also want to pass `--sysconfdir=$HOME/etc` and you might pass `--program-suffix=-mine` (to later run `git-mine` instead of `git`)

I strongly recommend to run `configure`  with `--help` at first, and to read the `INSTALL` file of your particular software (before compilation time), e.g. [this](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) for `git`

You may also need to deal with *dependencies* (be aware of the [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)), so you might need to install other libraries (and perhaps even adjust your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add `$HOME/soft/lib/` to it, etc).

See also [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/)

Read the [*Installing GIT*](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) chapter (notably *Installing from Source*)

In some cases having a discussion with your sysadmin could be easier.

Comment: What should be the path that I should add to .bashrc file?

Comment: The right one. You need to read more about `bash`, Unix shells, `$PATH`, `~/.bashrc`, etc. You need to understand more Linux. Spend a few days reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply choose a `prefix` that you have permission on, e.g. a folder inside your user's home:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/
make install
```

Then you will have to add `$HOME/opt/bin/` into your `PATH` env-var.

Comment: Might not work if the shell is not expanding `~` in the middle of an argument